# Combining (merging) indexes on SOLR, instead of inner joining tables in DIH

Tags: solr, indexing

Can I simply combine index files based on a unique id field, rather then run a multiple join  in DIH, on DB (which is really slow). In that case I can run simple queries witch are resolved more faster, and after that combine them, hoping that will be more fast and more cost efficient (on DB side). Anybody worked like that?
I found that: [artical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343574/merging-index-with-solr-1-4), but I'm using solr 3.4. Any better solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Materialized View, instead of doing multiple joins.

The solution mentioned in the article would work with Solr 4.0 as well.
However, it is a client side solution and would take more time then the normal approach.

Comment: Thanks, you miss the link for the mentioned articol?

Comment: i meant the same article posted by you, should not be Solr dependant

Comment: What if I'm using transformer scripts in data-config.xml?